# How can i change a date string format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm returning from Facebook Graph a friend birthday in MM/DD/YYY format. I need to show it in DD/MM/YYY, cause it's the brazil date format. I'am returnin a M/D string. I cant change the datetime format. How can I only display D/M for the user without changing datetime? Only manipulating the returning string?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: try `yourdatevalue.toString("D/M");`

Comment: Please refer to the MSDN documentation; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: For example. My friend's birthday is 02/01 (February 1) i need to show the user (01/02 - February 1 in pt-br format)

Comment: Error: Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: is the date you are trying to format a `DateTime` or a `String`?

Answer (score 2):

The error that you're receiving tells me that your birthday variable is a `string`. To format it, you can first convert it to a `DateTime` (it's probably the simplest way).

```
var birthdayString = "06/28/2013";
var date = Convert.ToDateTime(birthdayString);

date.ToString("dd/MM - MMMM d"); // 28/06 - June 28
date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); // 28/06/2013
```

Like I said in the comments above, you can check out more about formatting dates here:

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the format just take your date to string.

```
 birthdaydate.ToString("dd/MM/YYYY"); //10/01/1970
   birthdaydate.ToString("dd MMMM"); // 10 January
   birthdaydate.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY"); //01/10/1970
```

and so on. please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx for further information

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to input the format manually, you can do this instead:

```
string dateString = myDateTime.ToString(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
```